# Open paper animation in iOS using Core animation

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, core-animation, calayer

[image]

How to achieve this iOS 7 paper folding animation using CALayer. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want t achieve an effect like that you should start to learn about `CALayer`s in particular this subclass `CATransformLayer` and its property `-sublayerTransform`.

> CATransformLayer objects are used to create true 3D layer hierarchies,
>   rather than the flattened hierarchy rendering model used by other
>   CALayer classes.
>
> Unlike normal layers, transform layers do not flatten their sublayers
>   into the plane at Z=0.

This is a good starting point [Create a fold animation](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-3d-page-folding-animation-page-sketch-spine-fold-effect--mobile-13473).

Answer (score 1):

Hope this could help, get example in  https://github.com/mpospese/MPFoldTransition